# Bash - redirect stdout to log and screen with stderr only to log

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout, stderr, tee

I would like to do the following;

1. Redirect a copy of stdout to logfile and keep stdout on the screen.
2. Redirect stderr to the same logfile and not display on the screen.

*Code without stdout to screen*:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> >(sed -u 's/^/INF: /' >> common.log)
exec 2> >(sed -u 's/^/ERR: /' >> common.log)
echo "some txt"
echo "an error" >&2
echo "some more txt"
echo "one more error" >&2
```

*Log*:

```
INF: some txt
INF: some more txt
ERR: an error
ERR: one more error
```

The first issue is buffering which I tried to negate with sed '-u' for unbuffered.

*Code with stdout to screen*:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> >(sed -u 's/^/INF: /' | tee -a common.log)
exec 2> >(sed -u 's/^/ERR: /' >> common.log)
echo "some txt"
echo "an error" >&2
echo "some more txt"
echo "one more error" >&2
```

Results in the screen hanging (had to Ctrl-C) and log still buffered. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
command 2> >(sed -u 's/^/ERR: /' >> common.log) | sed -u 's/^/INF: /' | tee -a common.log
```

Where `command` is your command.

Comment: For a given command yes, but I'd like the whole namespace hence using exec. I could wrap specific sections in {} or on the function itself and use your solution but it's not ideal.

Comment: I'm marking this as answer given there is no better alternative.